# How to open a new window with customize size in inAppBrowser Android Cordova?

Tags: html, css, cordova

```
function inapp(){
   window.open('http://www.google.com','popUpWindow',
      'height=450,width=400,left=600,top=120,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
}
```

I am new to phonegap framework. now I am try to set the width and height of the window but it's not working . Pls anyone help me.

Comment: Have you fixed this problem? I have the same problem...

Comment: Not yet. i think it is not possible open a new window in popup

Comment: Why are you trying to set a size on a *mobile* window, it's always full-screen